# Angular authentication logic as separate application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have angular2 app. I'd like to put authentication logic as a separate application.

Reasons of separating:

1. Login / Sing up views have completely different design. Even on body level.
2. Login view should not load all sources of main application.
3. I'd like to show the first view very fast.

It looks like routing is the main problem.
How to organize splitting routes between applications?
**/signin** and **/signup** links should redirect to authentication app.
When **/customers** link should redirect to main app.

Comment: That's a pretty vague question. What does "different application" mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "different application"? same angular authentication app? other platform app? any third party app? or same application with different authentication module?

Answer (score 1):

If you want different application (running as separate web app) the routing should happen in the web server and not in the application, so the redirection should point to the different index.htmls... But this really depends on your environment, express, IIS, etc

If you just would like to split the code than you can create a different module for Authentication and reference it from you app as any other node modules. In this case if you don't want to load the code immediately you can use the dynamic component loader in angular2 to load the code in demand (this almost as separate app).